# Algolia filter by nested attribute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, search, indexing, algolia

So I am using Algolia.com to index users for quick searching.

An example object in index:

```
{
    id: 1,
    username: "john.doe",
    name: "John Doe",
    attributes: {
        gender: "male",
        hair_color: "blonde",
        eye_color: "blue",
        height: 165
    }
}
```

I'd like to filter results by a specific attribute (object key) in the attributes object.

I thought maybe using `facetFilters` would do the job, but I am unable to get it working.

I have tried many variances of this code:

```
user_index.search('', {
    facets: '*',
    facetFilters: ['attributes.hair_color:blonde', 'attributes.eye_color:blue']
}, function(error, data) {
    console.log(error, data);
});
```

-- / --

```
user_index.search('', {
    facets: '*',
    facetFilters: ['hair_color:blonde']
}, function(error, data) {
    console.log(error, data);
});
```

Please find the documentation here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript

Comment: Have you added `attributes.hair_color` to your `attributesForFaceting` (Display tab in your index dashboard) ? You should be able to easily just do `user_index.search('', { facetFilters: 'attributes.hair_color:blonde' }, function () { console.log(arguments); })` to search.

Comment: @Jerska Thank you! This has solved my issue! Something so simple.

Comment: @LeviCole There is *nothing* simple about Algolia's search API. It's insanely over-engineered and makes it incredibly difficult to perform the simplest search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in order to be able to mark this question as answered :

You should add `attributes.hair_color` to your `attributesForFaceting` (Display tab in your index dashboard)
You should be able to easily just do

```
user_index.search('', {
  facetFilters: 'attributes.hair_color:blonde'
}, function () {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

to search.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like using facet filters is the best way to achieve what you're looking for. The easiest way is to handle those filters is probably to use the Javascript Helper https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#filtering-results.

You would then only need to call

```
helper.addFacetRefinement('hair_color', 'blonde').search();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This didn't actually help unfortunately but it's good to know for the future!