# Algolia filter down nested array values

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have the following in the Algolia index:

```
{
    objectID: 1,
    subject: 'yyy',
    messages: [
        {visible: false, content: 'password: xxx'},
        {visible: true, content: 'qqq'},
    ]
}
```

Some users can see invisible messages, the other don't.
Is it possible to filter down `messages` only to {visible: true} ones?

The reason is that I don't want the invisible messages to show up in the xhr query response.

Comment: I can tell you how to filter them out clientside with Javascript, but I think you want them not to be sent by the server already?

Comment: yeah, that's the point

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it with one request to Algolia. What you can do is add 'message_visibility_false' and 'message_visibility_true' as attributes to main object.

```
{
objectID: 1,
subject: 'yyy',
message_visibility_false: 'password: xxx',
message_visibility_true: 'qqq'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using [*dot notation*](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/ranking/searchable-attributes/#nested-attributes). Try the following query:

```
 messages.visible = true
```

Make sure you add `messages.visible` to your `attributesForFaceting` in Algolia console.

This seems to be a duplicate from another issue though: [Algolia filter by nested attribute JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910947/algolia-filter-by-nested-attribute-javascript)